# How to customize/extend WordPress without getting impacted from future core/plugin updates?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-hook

I'm developing a website and need to customize WordPress using any of the following possible approaches:

1. Search & Use native WordPress plugins as per the business requirement and customize them for as per the (business) requirement! `This methods is easy to move with, although gets difficult to keep the customizations in sync with plugin's future updates.`
2. Should go ahead and write own custom-plugins for intended/specific features and manage/maintain. It also helps keeping the customization-code isolated. `Using this method requires lots of development efforts, regular efforts for future-compatibility (more or less deprives us from community benefits, that come with WordPress and its plugin-community)`

I wonder, how mature WordPress practitioners achieve future compatibility with **WordPress Core**, **Plugins** & **Themes** etc. for custom  application development and what are the best practices to keep WordPress custom development compatible with future updates?

Comment: The issue with modifying core code and/or plugin code directly is that updates to core or the plugin will overwrite those modifications.

Comment: Yes, I think same, so how to keep the best of WordPress meeting the business objectives? Though, this may sound a bit naive but has become a critical consideration for myself. Hoping to learn something, don't know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - **never** modify the core WordPress files. There may be some circumstances where you have to, but if you have to ask the question "can/should I modify core files for this"? The answer is no.

Secondly - you shouldn't be modifying plugin or theme files either, because modifications will be lost in updates.

Now, about best practice. Typically, you'll find a plugin that works *well enough* to accomodate your client's needs and call it good. Many *Good* plugins will have relatively straightforward ways to modify or extend them using custom hooks or template overrides (look at [Extending Gravity Forms](https://docs.gravityforms.com/category/extending-gravity-forms/) with plugins, hooks, etc. as well as [extending WooCommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/) again with plugins, hooks, filters, template overrides, or custom API).

Outside of *extending* plugins (**not** editing files directly), your best alternative is to write custom code to introduce the desired functionality, though that begins to introduce the issue of falling back to your for updates/security/maintenance, etc.

So, never modify core files or plugin files. Either extend plugin functionality, or write your own code to achieve said functionality.

Comment: I've marked this as an accepted answer already, though, if you may add more details, references to it, would be great. Highly appreciated - thanks.